# Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server

Tags: apache, centos

Server is Cent OS.

The httpd was working properly that is why I shut down the whole server to take snapshot. After the reboot the httpd was not working anymore, here is error from `jorunalctl`:

```
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Mar 16 12:47:49 ragnar01.novalocal httpd[2350]: httpd (pid 2322) already running
Mar 16 12:47:49 ragnar01.novalocal kill[2351]: kill: cannot find process ""
Mar 16 12:47:49 ragnar01.novalocal systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 16 12:47:49 ragnar01.novalocal systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Mar 16 12:47:49 ragnar01.novalocal systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Mar 16 12:47:49 ragnar01.novalocal systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Mar 16 12:47:49 ragnar01.novalocal polkitd[779]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2335:24998 (system bus name :1.13, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Mar 16 12:48:00 ragnar01.novalocal sshd[2332]: Connection closed by 123.183.209.139 [preauth]
```

I will be glad for all the ideas to start it again.

Comment: Looks like there is an old pid file in your filesystem

Comment: You may have to post this question on ServerFault instead of StackOverflow:  http://serverfault.com/

Comment: try `ps ax | grep a[p]ache\\\|h[t]tp`. If no answer try to delete pid file.

Comment: `ps ax | grep a[p]ache\\\|h[t]tp`  : 
 `2322 ?        Ss     0:00 httpd -k start`
 `2323 ?        S      0:00 httpd -k start`
 `2324 ?        S      0:00 httpd -k start`
 `2325 ?        S      0:00 httpd -k start`
 `2326 ?        S      0:00 httpd -k start`
 `2327 ?        S      0:00 httpd -k start`

Comment: Maybe `killall httpd` before `service httpd restart`

Comment: `killall` actually helped, the httpd started, but there is another problem, when I do the curl on the server ip, it will download the page, but in the browser the page wont show. The httpd.conf listen line looks like this: `Listen 80`